# WIX Burn custom install page

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, burn

I'd like to insert a "page" between the Burn's main page, and the installation process.

Is it possible to do without modifying the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp`?

If not, how should I link the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.cpp` to my burn project in VS2012?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding it is not possible to insert additional page without modifying WixStandardBootstrapperApplication (available in WiX sources). You need to add reference to the customized WixStandardBootstrapperApplication dll in your Visual Studio project and add the namespace reference xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" in WiX Burn project.
you may refer http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.co.uk/ for example.

Or you may write custom .net UI as per your requirement or if only a theme change is required, you can customize the Theme.